# Handling constantly updating fields in solr and preventing constantly reloading index?

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I'm running solr 6.3.0 with zookeeper/cloud.

I have a 'product' core that with a few integer/boolean fields that are getting updated constantly...a specific example would be inventory count.I have these working currently with an external file fields.  This setup accomplishes my goal of not having solr constantly reindexing.  However I don't like having to generate these files. I would rather handle have the come directly from my database.

It seems like atomic/partial updates is what I am looking for but I'm having trouble understanding the efficiency ramifications of these updates vs using external file fields...or perhaps there is a better approach all together.

I would appreciate any you could provide

Answer (score 0):

ExternalFileField is useful when you want to change the values of a field in many/all of the docs at the same time. If that is not the case, I would just use a normal field and update as needed (with partial updates is possible). With the external file you don't need to reindex but you do need to reload the file...

Regarding efficiency, for sure, the less frequently you update your docs the better, you have to reach a balance.

Comment: Using commitWithin together with frequent updates will probably be the most performant, as it allows Solr to batch the actual updates to the index for a commit. In this case tuning the field values should [make it possible to perform in-place updates](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html#UpdatingPartsofDocuments-In-PlaceUpdates) as well.

Comment: for sure, all the usual good practices apply regarding updating/committing. For instance the less frequently you hard commit the better (regarding perf) etc...